# Android - Update TextView periodically

Tags: android, service

I simply want to update a TextView periodically by a service. Let's say the TextView should display the time and update itself every 30 seconds. Could't you guys tell me how I can achieve that? I know that I need a receiver for that but everything I tried did't work at all.

I'm new to android, maybe you can keep it simple :D

Comment: Post your code then....

Comment: post code than some one help u

Comment: Show what have tried and where you face difficulties?

Comment: I tried it with an AlarmManager in my Receiver class. This way it should restart the service in an given period of time right? But to be honest with you guys I don't know how to use the processed data from the Service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In onCreate()      //updating every 30 seconds

```
      Handler handler =new Handler();
      final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);
                    String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    edittextId.setText(mydate);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 0000);
```

Comment: This code will keep on running even when the app is in background, until it is killed. It is neater to make use of onResume/onPause to start/stop the thread ([see the Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)).

Answer (score 3):

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 30000; //milliseconds

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        editText.setText(java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+"");
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```