# Infinite Loop Thread Cause UI to Freeze

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a UI component that must be continuously updated. I tried to add the update process to the UI thread like this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    speedometer.setValue((int) speed);
                }

        }
    });
```

But this causes the app to freeze. Why does this happen?

Comment: it happens because u're blocking the UI thread. U can never ever do on Android an infinite loop on the UI thread (and probably shouldn't do on any other thread too).

Comment: You should do something like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26466696/4860513 and update the UI periodically.... and never constantally

Answer (score 1):

The problem caused by `getActivity().runOnUiThread`  this basically say "do stuff inside run function on the main UI thread."

Use the next code to create a new thread inside the activity and not on the UI thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true) {
                speedometer.setValue((int) speed);
                handler.post(this);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this exception when I try to run things not on the UI thread: 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to run that on the UI thread - it'll block forever. You're running *the infinite loop itself* on the UI thread, thus preventing it from doing any other work. The only part of this that actually needs to run on the UI thread is the part that actually updates the UI itself. Have it run on a background thread and only call RunOnUIThread when you're actually doing an update.

Incidentally, why are you doing this process continuously? (If I remember correctly you can get away with around 20 milliseconds or so before it's perceivable to the human eye, so it's not necessary to do the updates that frequently).