# How to modify textview text after N seconds from string-array using Handler?

Tags: java, android, handler

I want to change the text of a textview after n seconds using handler. The various strings are present in a array of strings. (Updating a textview on the UI)

The following code makes the app crash everytime. what to do?

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView textView;
Handler handler = new Handler();
String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.wat1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        int len = arr.length;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(arr[len-1]);
            len--;
            if(len!=0){
                handler.postDelayed(this,2000);
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(r);
}
```

}

Comment: Share what exactly you are doing for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Update TextView periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466451/android-update-textview-periodically)

Answer (score 0):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(yourArray[0]); //set text here
        }
    }, 1000); //1000 = 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handper.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

Where **runnable** is your action to change the text, and 3000 is the time in millis, where 3000 is equal to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
        textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // set text 
                textView.setText("Text");

            }
        },300) // Time in millisecond
```